# CommandButton doesn't work primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

while developing a demo erp web application for hospital i faced a problem with primefaces component `<p:commandButton>`,it doesn't send the request to the server to a specified method. I integrated Spring Core with hibernate and primefaces.

```
Here is main.xhtml 
this page resposible for getting the required tab to show on screen
```

```
<pe:layout fullPage="true" options="#{mainService.layoutOptionsOne}" rendered="true" state="true">
    <pe:layoutPane position="west">
        <p:accordionPanel value="#{accordionPanelController.tabs}" var="accordionTab">
            <p:tab title="#{accordionTab.title}">
                <p:tree value="#{accordionTab.rootNode}" var="data">
                    <p:treeNode>
                        <h:form id="form">
                            <p:commandLink value="#{data.sectionLabel}"
                                update=":tabView :tabView:#{tabController.activeTabIndex}:tab"
                                actionListener="#{tabController.openTab(data.screenId)}" />

                        </h:form>

                    </p:treeNode>
                </p:tree>
            </p:tab>
        </p:accordionPanel>
    </pe:layoutPane>
    <pe:layoutPane id="tabLayout" position="center">
        <p:tabView id="tabView" value="#{tabController.tabs}" var="tab" dynamic="true"
            activeIndex="#{tabController.activeTabIndex}"
            onTabClose="#{tabController.closeTab(tab.screenId)}" scrollable="true">
            <p:tab id="tab" title="#{tab.title}" closable="#{tab.closable}">

                <p:panel rendered="#{tab.screenId == 'DEFAULT'}" style="border:none;">
                    <ui:include src="/default.xhtml" />
                </p:panel>

                <p:panel rendered="#{tab.screenId == 'DOCTOR_TAB'}">
                    <ui:include src="/doctor/doctor-list-tab.xhtml" />
                </p:panel>


            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>

    </pe:layoutPane>
</pe:layout>
```

doctor-list-tab.xhtml
this page responsible for displaying a list of all doctors and provide to buttons for create a new one and to edit existing one

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<h:head>
    <style type="text/css">
.ui-ribbon .ui-colorpicker .ui-button {
    height: 24px;
}

.ui-ribbon .ui-ribbon-group .ui-ribbon-group-content {
    height: 4em;
    padding: 0.2em 0.2em 0;
}

.ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-new {
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    background-image: url("#{resource['icons/new.png']}");
}

.ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-save {
    background-image: url("#{resource['icons/save.png']}");
}

.ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-paste {
    background-image: url("#{resource['icons/paste.png']}");
}

.ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-cut {
    background-image: url("#{resource['icons/cut.png']}");
}

.ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-print {
    background-image: url("#{resource['icons/print.png']}");
}

.ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-zoomin {
    background-image: url("#{resource['icons/zoomin.png']}");
}

.ui-icon.ui-ribbonicon-zoomout {
    background-image: url("#{resource['icons/zoomout.png']}");
}

.ui-tabs-nav.ui-helper-reset.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-widget-header.ui-corner-all {
    width: auto;
}

.ui-ribbon-group-content {
    height: 70px;
}
</style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
        <p:ribbon style="width:auto; height:auto;">
            <p:tab title="File">
                <p:ribbonGroup label="Options" id="options">
                    <p:commandButton value="New" action="#{doctorListTabController.newRecord}"
                        styleClass="ui-ribbon-bigbutton" icon="ui-ribbonicon-new" process="@this" />

                    <p:commandButton value="Save" icon="ui-ribbonicon-save" styleClass="ui-ribbon-bigbutton" />

                </p:ribbonGroup>
            </p:tab>
        </p:ribbon>

        <p:dataTable id="doctors" var="doctor" value="#{doctorListTabController.doctors}"
            draggableColumns="true" resizableColumns="true" style="margin-top:20px" selectionMode="single"
            selection="#{doctorListTabController.selectedRecord}" rowKey="#{doctor.id}" paginator="true">
            <f:facet name="header">
            List of Doctors
            </f:facet>
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{doctorListTabController.onRecordSelect}"
                update=":tabView:#{tabController.activeTabIndex}:doctors" />
            <p:column headerText="Id">
                <h:outputText value="#{doctor.id}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{doctor.name}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Age">
                <h:outputText value="#{doctor.age}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="address">
                <h:outputText value="#{doctor.address}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="mobile">
                <h:outputText value="#{doctor.mobile}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="email">
                <h:outputText value="#{doctor.email}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="gender">
                <h:outputText value="#{doctor.gender}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Scoiality">
                <h:outputText value="#{doctor.sociality}" />
            </p:column>


            <p:column headerText="Degree">
                <h:outputText value="#{doctor.degree}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="SSN">
                <h:outputText value="#{doctor.ssn}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
</h:body>
</html>
```

DoctorListTablController.java

```
package com.admin.doctor.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.server.doctor.Doctor;
import com.server.doctor.DoctorManagerImpl;

public class DoctorListTabController implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<Doctor> doctors;
    private DoctorManagerImpl doctorManager;
    private Doctor selectedRecord;

    public DoctorListTabController() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Doctor> getDoctors() {
        return doctorManager.load(Doctor.class);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Doctor> loadAll() {
        return doctorManager.load(Doctor.class);
    }

    public void setDoctors(List<Doctor> doctors) {
        this.doctors = doctors;
    }

    public DoctorManagerImpl getDoctorManager() {
        return doctorManager;
    }

    public void setDoctorManager(DoctorManagerImpl doctorManager) {
        this.doctorManager = doctorManager;
    }

     public void onRecordSelect(SelectEvent event) {
           System.out.println(((Doctor) event.getObject()).getId());
     }

    public Doctor getSelectedRecord() {
        return selectedRecord;
    }

    public void setSelectedRecord(Doctor selectedRecord) {
        this.selectedRecord = selectedRecord;
    }

    public void newRecord() {
        Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        options.put("modal", true);
        options.put("width", 640);
        options.put("height", 340);
        options.put("contentWidth", "100%");
        options.put("contentHeight", "100%");
        options.put("headerElement", "customheader");

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("/doctor/new-doctor.xhtml", options, null);
 }

}
```

Actually i cauldn't know why `<p:commandButton>` didn't invoke `newMethod`

I'll be thankful if somebody help me
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to instantiate `DoctorListTabController` by using `@ManagedBean`.  I don't see here that you did that.

Comment: It is not working because you do not have a <h:form> for your page. The <h:form> tag is responsible to send everything to the managed bean you just put it for one button. You have to envolve everything with it. Remember to not add an h:form inside another one. There should be just one.

Comment: SRy, i put the bean inside Spring context not @ManagedBean

Comment: @JorgeCampos , i tried to put the button inside `<h:form>` but failed

Comment: Edit your post with your attempt to see how you set it up. Also point which button is not working;

Comment: @JorgeCampos button "new" in doctor-list-tab.xhtml file

Comment: And where is the form tag on it?